# M2 Search engine in block

Tags: magento2, blocks, catalogsearch

I'm looking if it's possible to put the search engine in a block.
What I use at the moment is:

```
{{block class="Magento\Search\Block\Term" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml"}}
```

But if I add a module for the autocomplete it doesn't work.
So, maybe I don't use the right code for the block...

Some help will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Until I know it can be moved to one Container.

If for example you want to create custom container in header and move search there, you can edit your default.xml

> [Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

and include:

```
<move element="top.search" destination="your.container" />
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="your.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="your-container" />
</referenceContainer>
```